# Why does ActiveRecord allow me to sort by a nonexistent column name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Both of these lines of code return perfectly valid `ActiveRecord::Relation` collection of `Books`:

```
Book.order(:bazqux)
---> SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY "bazqux" ASC LIMIT ?
Book.order(bazqux: :desc)
---> SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY "bazqux" DESC LIMIT ?
```

But when I try with SQL I get an error:

```
Book.order("bazqux DESC")
---> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: bazqux: SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY bazqux DESC LIMIT ?)

conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
conn.execute("SELECT  books.* FROM books ORDER BY books.bazqux ASC LIMIT ?", 10)
---> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: books.bazqux: SELECT  books.* FROM books ORDER BY books.bazqux ASC LIMIT ?)
```

Why is this?

Comment: You are trying to directly execute SQL, The AR behaviour is as expected. AR does not inspect your schema. In other works, AR does not (nor it should) validate the raw sql queries. It does this because you might be connecting to a database table for which the schema does not match the model.

Comment: I see.  In this example, in the case where the schema doesn't match the model, would there be an attribute on `Book` called `bazqux` that maps to a differently-named column?